# Eisenstein series of congruence subgroup

Tags: modular-arithmetic, modular-forms

Let $P$ be a prime number, and let $k >2$ be a positive even integer.
Now I want to compute the Fourier expansion of the Eisenstein  series of $\Gamma_0(p)$ at the cusp $0$, i.e.,
$$
E_{k, 0}(z) = \sum_{\gamma \in  \Gamma_0 \backslash \Gamma} j( S \gamma S^{-1}, z)^k.
$$
Here $\Gamma=\Gamma_0(P)$, $\Gamma_0$ is the stabilizer of the cusp $0$ in $\Gamma$, and $S=\begin{pmatrix}0&{-1}\\1&0\\ \end{pmatrix}$.

I only see one example in the text to compute fourier expansion, which is very different with this one. Basically I have no idea about how to handle this. So where can I find similar examples of calculation?

Comment: I deal with something quite similar to this in my recent preprint: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07256v1.pdf. If you need further details, let me know.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Thanks, I will look it up!